# preg_replace() escaping: single vs double backslash?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I noticed someone using preg_replace() with double backslashes to escape, (e.g., `<\\/div>` instead of `<\/div>`).

**Is this necessary?** I tried both ways and I don't see what's the difference.

simple example...

`preg_replace('/<div>\\s*text<\\/div>/', '', $somestring);`

vs

`preg_replace('/<div>\s*text<\/div>/', '', $somestring);`

Comment: Double escape is necessary if you use double quotes for your string (PHP will try to interpret the `\ ` in the string, so you need to escape once for the string, once for the regex). It's useless with single quoted strings (unless you want to use a literal `\ ` in your regex). See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for the diff.

Answer (score 1):

A backslash in a *PHP string literal* can have a special meaning. For example `"\n"` is a newline, not the string "\n". To write the string "\n", you need to escape the backslash as `"\\n"`. However, if the character following the backslash doesn't have any special meaning, the backslash is taken as is. E.g. `"\foo"` is the string "\foo". In single-quoted strings there's only a single case in which you *need* to escape the backslash, which is directly before the end of the string: `'foo\\'` → "foo\".

So, writing `\\/` in a PHP string literal or `\/` has the same meaning, because `/` does not have any special significance to PHP. Either way is correct. This is not about regex syntax but about PHP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary when you using single quote, it makes no difference in your code example.
*(For using double quote, it's only necessary when combine with the next char has special meaning)*

For single quotes( and so does double quotes), backslash has to be escaped only when it's the last character of the string.

You have to write `'foo\\'` instead of `'foo\'` or backslash will escape the single quote and leads syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
preg_replace('%<div>\s*text</div>%', '', $somestring);
```

In this case, you don't need to escape anything.

**PHP - Escape sequences**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: To match one literal ``\`` in a PHP string literal regex you'll have to escape it a few more times: `'/\\\\/'`